# How do you check if each character of a list is in a string?

Tags: python, string

How do you check if each character of a list is in a string? For example, how would I check if each character of the list ['h','e','l','p'] is in string 'abcdhfeigjklmopnqrsvutwxyz" in order?

By way of example, it would look like this:

abcd**H**feigjklmopnqrsvutwxyz
abcdhf**E**igjk**L**mo**P**nqrsvutwxyz

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: You need to return to your materials on strings, and learn how to determine whether a particular character is in a string.  This is a specific use of the operation you use to find any element in any sequence.  You also need to return to your materials on sequences, and learn how to iterate through the elements.

Comment: The best way to do this is with a regular expression, but Prune is exactly right about scope.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings support `in` to check if a character exists within the string, e.g. `'a' in 'bcdaef' == True`. Iterate over the list of characters and test if any of them don't exist:

```
def all_characters_in_string(check_list, my_string):
    exists = True
    for c in check_list:
        if c not in my_string:
            exists = False
    return exists
```

You can easily do this with `all()`:

```
all(c in my_string for c in check_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "abcdhfeigjklmopnqrsvutwxyz"
ch = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p']

print( len(set(s) & set(ch)) == len(set(ch))  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume ['h','e','l','p'] are all lower case,if it not,you may need to tranfer to the lower case.

1.count every elements index in line,may appear repeatedly
2.loop ['h','e','l','p'] if each minimum index is larger then last one then is in oder.

```py
def get_show_position(targets,sentence):
    s = {}
    for i,e in enumerate(sentence):
        lower_case = e.lower()
        if lower_case in targets:
            s.setdefault(lower_case,[]).append(i)
    return s

def is_order(targets,s):
    order_index = -1
    for n in targets:
        index_list = s.get(n,[])
        if index_list == []:
            return False
        else:
            mins = min(index_list)
            if order_index <mins:
                order_index = mins
            else:
                return False
    return True

targets = ['h','e','l','p']
sentence = "abcdHfeigjklmopnqrsvutwxyz abcdhfEigjkLmoPnqrsvutwxyz"
position = get_show_position(targets,sentence)
status = is_order(targets,position)
print(status)
```